# Debian SMB share having permission issues in windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, samba

I setup a Debian squeeze server with samba. I then shared my /media directory with the following configuration:

```
[media]
    comment=Hard Drives
    read only = no
    locking = no
    path = /media
    guest ok = yes
    browsable = yes
    directory mask = 0777
```

When the drives are mapped in Windows 7, the user can write to all of the subdirectories of media (`sdb1`, `sdc1`, etc), but cannot write to any folders that they create themselves in the subdirectories of media. For example, if the user mapped `/media/sdb1` to `Z:`, and then creates a folder `Z:\test`, the folder is created successfully, but no files can be written to `Z:\test`. If the user ssh's into the server, they have no problems writing to these directories. I have included the screenshots, in order, of what happens on Windows. This samba share is mounted with ntfs-3g, if it makes a difference.

[Screenshots are here](http://xxpor.imgur.com/samba_issue)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is it says you need login Unix User\root  so are you mapping/logging in with the user root or SOME_USER ?

Secondly, you will possibly need to explicitly define:
writable = yes

as according to documentation.

Lastly can you please check the log for any errors?

Oh and also, does it work on any other systems ie winxp, its just broken for w7?